# Regular expression slug before another word

Tags: php, .htaccess, slug

I'm making a writer's website and I want to showcase some books, and then some excerpts.

I want the URLs to look like this:
site.com/book/name-of-book
site.com/book/name-of-book/excerpt

I managed to do the first part with this htacess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Remove .php from regular pages
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Directory style books
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ ./book.php?slug=$1

# Directory style books excerpts
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)/excerpt$ ./book-excerpt.php?slug=$1
```

My problem is the second part as it is not working, the `book.php` is loaded, instead of `book-excerpt.php`.

I've been researching on how to do this, but all solutions throughout the web seem to not work for me. What am I doing wrong?
Is the first rule overriding the second? How can I fix this?

Comment: And "it is not woriking" means _what_ ? Do you get an error? Which? Does the client hang? How long? Do you receive a falthy answer? Which? Does the universe implode? We cann _guess_ that, you need to _tell_ us.

Comment: The issue most likely is the order of processing: since the last-but-one rule _always_ matches there is no way the last rule will ever get applied. Change their order!

Comment: @arkascha added some details. I tried changing the order, as you said, but the result was the same.

Comment: @arkascha the first rule follows the same ideal as the last-but-one. By swaping all the rules 1-2-3 to 3-2-1 I could make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Since the rules were overriding each other, swaping all of them (1-2-3 to 3-2-1) made it work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# Directory style books excerpts
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)/excerpt$ ./book-excerpt.php?slug=$1

# Directory style books
RewriteRule ^book/(.*)$ ./book.php?slug=$1

# Remove .php from regular pages
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```